Can´t access directory I just created in home folder QNAP
[david@qnap_nas ~]$ pwd
/share/homes/david

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ whoami
david

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ id
uid=1024(david) gid=100(everyone) groups=0(administrators),100(everyone)

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ mkdir test_dir

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ ls -lah test_dir/
/bin/ls: cannot open directory test_dir/: Permission denied

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ sudo ls -lah test_dir/
total 17K
drwxrwx---  2 david everyone  2 2024-05-03 10:44 .
drwxrwx--- 14 david everyone 24 2024-05-03 10:44 ..

[david@qnap_nas ~]$ cd test_dir/
-sh: cd: test_dir/: Permission denied

As you can see, others have no permissions ---, I found out that chmod o+x allows me to enter the folder I just created, but I'm not sure if this is a bandaid fix or the actual fix (because my home folder /share/homes/david has the same permissions as /share/homes/david/test_dir I just created and I can access one but not the other).

Please edit your question to include the permissions on the directory itself sudo ls lah test_dir. I think that the difference is in the permissions associated with the directory itself rather than its content.

That's be drwxrwx---  2 david everyone  2 2024-05-03 10:44 . in sudo ls lah test_dir/
